# Web hosting solutions allowing self-made Apache modules

Tags: apache-2.2, web-hosting

I am searching for a web hosting solution that would allow me to use my own Apache modules written in C.

Have you any idea who would offer that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any shared hosting solutions that would allow that. So your best option would be a virtual or dedicated server. This would give you root/admin access and the ability to install whatever Apache module you want.

Comment: +1 - No webhost in their right mind would allow you to install your own apache modules in their shared environment.  You're going to need a dedicated solution (real machine or VPS) to do this.